# Cleanliness of public toilets in the Philippines - myth or misconception?

Tags: philippines, toilets

I have read both articles in the past and more recently about the cleanliness of public toilets in the Philippines, more famously those of the Shell Gas Stations:

http://www.odditycentral.com/travel/shell-gas-station-toilets-in-the-philippines-are-so-clean-it-will-blow-your-mind.html

My lack of travel experience in this particular region in South East Asia and my general understanding about public toilets would suggest that this is an exception rather than the rule.

Can anyone who has been travelling in this country help clarify or verify these claims?

Comment: not an answer, but it is related : http://www.philippinespublictoilet.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, it depends. I haven't been to all Philippines (only to 14 or so cities), so take this with a grain of salt.

Every public toilet I used there was reasonably clean. Most weren't exactly as shown on your link, and some (for example on a local market in Cebu) didn't have running water (there's a bucket of water nearby and you flush with a ladle), but it didn't look or felt filthy. From my experience it's similar to Thailand, and way above a typical toilet in India.

What was common, however, was the lack of toilet paper. Even paid toilets sometime (not always) had only tissues, and usually for extra fee - although minor.

And as you guess, pay toilets and those closer to touristy areas are generally cleaner and more stocked.

Comment: +1 14 cities is quite a lot in my opinion :) From what I understood in the article there was a reason for the toilets in the gas stations to be 'glammed' up, which made me wonder if it would somehow raise the standard of other public toilets as well. I know China had issues with people stealing toilet paper in the past too and they had to implement extra security measures as a result.

Comment: Both cars and gas are expensive in Philippines, so it is likely gas station toilets are used mostly by people who are rich (by local standards) and by tourists (who are also rich by local standards). So I'd expect the gas station toilet to be in much better condition than one at a local market indeed. In China last year only once I didn't find toilet paper.